# Jumble word list by shaking the android phone

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have a view with a name list. I want to jumble the list when I shake the phone. I understand I have to use the accelerometer to detect shake but I am not sure how to jumble the name list. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: use sensor example given in api demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have the names stored as an array of strings, you can shuffle the array using the `Collection` class:

```
String[3] names = new String();
names[0] = "John";
names[1] = "Sam";
names[2] = "Sally";

//Now shuffle the names
names = Collection.shuffle(names);
```

You don't have to use an `Array` to do this, any object that is a child of `List` can be shuffled using `Collection.shuffle()`. For more info see the [Collection Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I did not ask my question correctly, how would I show it in the UI, the words moving around and shuffling.

Comment: What are you using to display the words? Are you using a ListView?  If so you simply need to tell the `Adapter` that the data set has changed, I think its with the `notifyDataSetChange()` method, although I dont know off the top of my head. I'm not sure how to go about animating the items in a list view.

Comment: Yes I am using the ListView. The animation is the part that I am unable to figure out.